# Manually created formula seems to not work...but why?

Tags: r, regression, formula

Let's consider data following :

```
library(pglm)
data('UnionWage', package = 'pglm')
df1 <- data.frame(UnionWage[1:2],'wage' = UnionWage$wage, 'exper' = UnionWage$exper)
head(df1)
  id year     wage exper
1 13 1980 1.197540     1
2 13 1981 1.853060     2
3 13 1982 1.344462     3
4 13 1983 1.433213     4
5 13 1984 1.568125     5
6 13 1985 1.699891     6
```

I want to write a function which will fit logistic random panel regression to data :

**Function**

```
fit_panel_binary <- function(y, x) {
   x <- cbind(x, y)
  #Taking varnames since 3 (first and second are respectively id and year)
  varnames <- names(x)[3:(length(x))]

  #Excluding dependent variable from varnames
  varnames <- varnames[!(varnames == names(y))]

  #Creating formula of independent variables (sum)
  form <- paste0(varnames, collapse = "+")
  x_copy <- data.frame(x)

  #Performing panel random regression
  model <- pglm(as.formula(paste0(names(y), "~", form)), data = as.matrix(x_copy), 
  model = 'random', family = binomial(link = 'logit'))
}
```

And error occrus :

```
fit_panel_binary(UnionWage['union'],df1)
Error in if (!id.name %in% names(x)) stop(paste("variable ", id.name,  : 
  argument is of length zero
```

I though that I put formula incorrectly so I changed my function to outputs formula `paste0(names(y), "~", form)`
and this is what I got :

```
"union~wage+exper"
```

It seems that formula is correct, but regression says something different. DO you know where is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, because of the way `pglm` captures its arguments using non-standard evaluation, it doesn't like being passed formulas that have to be evaluated (i.e. formulas that aren't typed in situ). You can get round this by calling it with `do.call`, but even then you have to be careful that the data is available in the frame in which `pglm` is called. So you have to do something like:

```r
fit_panel_binary <- function(y, x) {

  x <- cbind(x, y)
  varnames <- names(x)[3:(length(x))]
  varnames <- varnames[!(varnames == names(y))]
  form     <- paste0(varnames, collapse = "+")
  x_copy   <- data.frame(x)
  form     <- as.formula(paste(names(y), "~", form))
  params   <- list(formula = form, data = x_copy, model = "random",
                   family  = binomial(link = "logit"))
  pglm_env <- list2env(params, envir = new.env())
  
  do.call("pglm", params, envir = pglm_env)
}
```

Allowing:

```r
fit_panel_binary(UnionWage['union'], df1)
#> Maximum Likelihood estimation
#> Newton-Raphson maximisation, 6 iterations
#> Return code 1: gradient close to zero
#> Log-Likelihood: -1655.081 (4 free parameter(s))
#> Estimate(s): -3.428254 0.8305558 -0.06590541 4.2625
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>